# Docker X11 Forward get Blank Screen

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, x11, x11-forwarding

Im trying to use docker to contain my app and forward x11 to spawn Chrome with chromedriver.
I could make the browser spawn, but its spawn all blank. Also the context menu its blank. It closes without crashing.

Introductory information: (CAN BE SKIPPED)

I have an app (django+postgresql+supervisor+uwsgi+celery+redis+nginx+selenium) that spawn Chrome/Chromium browsers via Chromedriver with Selenium, opening them in diferent pre-loaded User Data Directories (with pre-loaded sessions and logins) and do some automated stuff in diferents sites.

Everything works smooth and clear in my computer.

Some co-workers ask me to install them my app. I told them it would only work on Linux, since i develop in Linux and im not sure if everything would work same in Windows.

After 1 of them installed Ubuntu, i tried to install everything with my source code, using my private git repo for sharing/updating, and it was extremelly painfull.

First, i had troubles installing the right Python Version, after that, supervisor was not working as i expected. Every step presented diferent troubles, and the app itselft presents some bugs that i dont have in my own environment.

The Trouble itself: (CAN START READING HERE)

So, after a lot of reading, i thought Docker would be fit great, even if its not designed to open desktops apps. A single X11 forward could fix the issue.

I went directly with a Docker-compose file (to speed up the parallel processes setup). This is actually my first time using docker, and its feels really easy. 
I made to make a Dockerfile and a docker-compose file that setups everything (right python version, chrome/chromedrivers and its dependencies) and everything -excepts Chrome- works great.

After doing some digging and testing with the X11 redirect, i could make my application Launch Chrome and spawn the Chrome windows in my host computer, but the window itselfs its blank. Even if do right click, the opening context menu its all blank.

I ran `xhost +local:root` on my host computer but that wont fix the issue.

I'vea read here http://wiki.ros.org/docker/Tutorials/GUI in the Part 3. The Isolated Way, that i should do something like this

````
```XSOCK=/tmp/.X11-unix
XAUTH=/tmp/.docker.xauth
touch $XAUTH
xauth nlist $DISPLAY | sed -e 's/^..../ffff/' | xauth -f $XAUTH nmerge -

docker run -it \
        --volume=$XSOCK:$XSOCK:rw \
        --volume=$XAUTH:$XAUTH:rw \
        --env="XAUTHORITY=${XAUTH}" \
        --env="DISPLAY" \
        -user="myNewUserName" \
    osrf/ros:indigo-desktop-full \
    rqt```
````

But im not sure how should i do the xauth list stuff inside the docker-compose file (or where should i?). Im actually not 100% sure that my issue is inside xauth.

Here is my docker file:
I choose Python 3.7.4-slim-strech since it:
* Provides me the right python version
* Debian can install chromium and chromedriver from its repositories (chromium version 73)
* Its the most easiest setup that i've found for my needs

```
FROM python:3.7.4-slim-stretch

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y chromium chromedriver build-essential

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# My Actual System Username, i've also tested with other username and i have the same issue
ENV USERNAME "gabriel"

# These UID and GID match mines
RUN export uid=1000 gid=1000 && \
    addgroup \
     --system \
     --gid ${gid} \
       ${USERNAME} && \
    adduser \
     --system \
     --uid ${uid} \
     --shell /bin/bash \
     --gid ${gid} \
       ${USERNAME} && \
    usermod -aG sudo ${USERNAME} && \
    passwd -d ${USERNAME}

RUN mkdir /app && \
    mkdir /config && \
    mkdir -p /var/www/static

ADD ./config /config
RUN pip install -r /config/requirements.pip

RUN chown -R ${uid}:${gid} /app && \
    chown -R ${uid}:${gid} /config && \
    chown -R ${uid}:${gid} /var/www && \
    chmod +x /config/application_launch.sh

USER ${USERNAME}
ENV HOME /home/${USERNAME}

WORKDIR /app

ADD ./src /app
```

And here is my docker compose file:

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: ps01

  supervisor:
    build: .
    command: supervisord -c /config/supervisord.conf
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app
      - ./src/static:/var/www/static
      - /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw
    ports:
      - "9001:9001"
    expose:
      - "8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    extra_hosts:
      - "yangoo.network:10.68.0.1"
    container_name: su01
    environment:
      - DISPLAY
      - UID
      - QT_X11_NO-MITSHM=1

  nginx:
    image: nginx
    container_name: wb01
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./src/static:/var/www/static
    depends_on:
      - supervisor
    links:
      - supervisor
```

**EDIT**:

Upgrading my distro to popos 19.04 fixed the blank screen issue. Also i could make it work in a Virtual Machine with a newer linux distro. The problem appear to be present only in older distros.

Comment: Did you consider a virtual machine for this application?  That has the advantage of being able to run a "native" display driver.  (If you're trying to support your Windows-based colleagues with this setup, they probably aren't running an X server and this trick might not work.)

Comment: I did. And i’ve made one with peppermint linux. But the file size is too big, and pushing updates is really easier with docker + git. My final thought was combine the vm + dockerized project for windows hosts and only the dockerized project for linux envs

Answer (score 2):

There is a Chromium bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1048186

According to the comments, adding `ipc: host` to your supervisor config in docker-compose will work:

```
supervisor:
    build: .
    command: supervisord -c /config/supervisord.conf
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app
      - ./src/static:/var/www/static
      - /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw
    ports:
      - "9001:9001"
    expose:
      - "8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    extra_hosts:
      - "yangoo.network:10.68.0.1"
    container_name: su01
    environment:
      - DISPLAY
      - UID
      - QT_X11_NO-MITSHM=1
    ipc: host
```